# How can I update my UserProfile model when the User model is updated Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a site where I need to update my UserProfileInfo model, which is how I am extending the User model.
However, whenever I save the User model, the UserProfileInfo does not, meaning in the admin, the User model has the `first_name` and `last_name` variables filled out, however the `UserProfileInfo` does not.

Here is some code.

**MODELS.PY**

```py
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,max_length=30)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
    image = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',
                                           processors=[ResizeToFill(150, 150)],
                                           default='default.jpg',
                                           format='JPEG',
                                           options={'quality': 60})
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True,default=timezone.now)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    moderator = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfileInfo.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        instance.userprofileinfo.save()
```

In the receiver, I want to update both, but it is not.

**FORMS.PY**

```py
class UserProfileInfoForms(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ['username','first_name','last_name','email']

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email']

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfileInfo
        fields = ['image','description','tags','website']
```

And finally here is the view

**VIEWS.PY**

```
@login_required
def profile_update(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.userprofileinfo)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('mainapp:profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.userprofileinfo)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }
    return render(request,'mainapp/profile_update.html',context)
```

So here, I'm saving both the UserUpdateForm and ProfileUpdateForm

And finally here are my signals

**SIGNALS.PY**

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfileInfo.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        instance.userprofileinfo.save()

@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def save_profile(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    instance.userprofileinfo.save()
```

I have also included my `signals.py` in the apps.py file, so it is working.

So how can I make it so that the UserProfileInfo model is updated when the User model is updated? I am having trouble figuring this out, so any help would is appreciated

Comment: How do you know it doesn't update? You are not changing anything in the `instance.userprofileinfo` instance, and the overridden `save` method doesn't do anything.

Comment: Because when the user is updated, in the admin panel, on the Users tab, it has the first_name and last_name filled out, however in the UserProfileInfo profile, it is not, and the fields are empty

Comment: You don't have any code to copy `first_name` and `last_name` fields from the `User` instance to `UserProfileInfo` instance. You are simply saving the existing object, without changing anything in that signal receiver. I also fail to see the reason why you have those fields in the user profile model. Why do you duplicate fields in different models? You can always use `userprofile.user.first_name` if you need that value.

Answer (score 0):

```
def profile_update(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():           
            p_form.instance.user=request.user
            p_form.instance.first_name=request.user.first_name
            p_form.instance.last_name=request.user.last_name
            p_form.instance.email=request.user.email                
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()            
            return redirect('mainapp:profile')   
        context = {       
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,
        }    
        return render(request, 'mainapp/profile_update.html', context)
```